# To sending XML data to multiple IP at a time from a server application

Tags: c#, tcp

I am facing a problem over sending XML data to multiple IP in a for loop,selected from the server side.The code that I'm using are given below.

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(pi);// "pi" is the selected IP address
IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 1234);
byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[100];
TcpClient client1 = new TcpClient(serverEndPoint);

Socket socket = client1.Client;
{
    socket.Connect(serverEndPoint);
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSet));

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(4096))
    //TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"D:\test.xml");
    //using (var stream = new System.Xml.XmlWriter())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, objDatasetSend);
    }

    //Send the serialized data.
    var networkStream = client1.GetStream();

    if (networkStream.CanWrite)
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(networkStream, objDatasetSend);
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: @Tyress I need to send the XML file to four different IP,but the files are being sent to only 1 IP,that also the first one selected from the four.